# Combining counts and merge column PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, count

How can I combine the two queries together to have 3 columns as a result? 
BR_SURG_SLN_POS and BR_SURG_NSLN_POS is always going to be 0-4 so if these two columns could be merged as one column since their values are the same. 
I would like the next two columns to be count(BR_SURG_SLN_POS) and count(BR_SURG_NSLN_POS). I tried using concat to merge the two columns but it isn't the result I wanted.

```
select 
br_surg_SLN_POS,
count(BR_SURG_SLN_POS)<BR>
from BR_SURGERY<BR>
where BR_SURG_SLN_POS between 0 and 4<BR>
group by 
BR_SURG_SLN_POS<BR>
order by 
BR_SURG_SLN_POS
```

---

```
select 
br_surg_NSLN_POS,
count(BR_SURG_NSLN_POS)<BR>
from BR_SURGERY<BR>
where BR_SURG_NSLN_POS between 0 and 4<BR>
group by 
BR_SURG_NSLN_POS<BR>
order by 
BR_SURG_NSLN_POS
```

---

Similar to this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select t1.sln_value, t1.sln_cnt , t2.nsln_cnt from
     (select 
         br_surg_SLN_POS sln_value,
        count(BR_SURG_SLN_POS) sln_cnt
     from BR_SURGERY
      where BR_SURG_SLN_POS between 0 and 4<BR>
        group by 
           BR_SURG_SLN_POS) t1,
    (select 
           br_surg_NSLN_POS nsln_value,
          count(BR_SURG_NSLN_POS) nsln_cnt
         from BR_SURGERY
        where BR_SURG_NSLN_POS between 0 and 4
           group by 
            BR_SURG_NSLN_POS ) t2
             where t1.sln_value = t2.nsln_value
           ;
```

Comment: Thanks Pawan Rawat! I see how you named the columns and joined the ones I needed merged. Very nice thank you very much!